# I am trying to ad a countdown timer to my maze game

Tags: c#

I am making a maze game

I wrote this:

```
 private int counter = 60;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int counter = 60;
            timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
            timer1.Interval = 1000; //one second
            timer1.Start();
            label1.Text = counter.ToString();

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            counter--;
            if (counter == 0)

                timer1.Stop();                
            label1.Text = counter.ToString();



            }
        }
    }
```

After this I want a `Messagebox` to appear when the timer ends on `0`. When I click on the OK button I want the form to close.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, you should do it.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (counter.Equals(0))
{
 if (MessageBox.Show("Time Ran out!") == DialogResult.OK)
 {
  this.Close();
  }
}
```

You actually don't even need the Dialog Result if it only has an OK. Which part are you having difficulty with anyway? Your code was almost compelte.

Comment: i am new with programming and wounder were i should wrote it :)

Comment: i figured it out. thanks anyway. this was just what i was looking for :)

Comment: private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            counter--;
            if (counter == 0)
            


                timer1.Stop();
                label1.Text = counter.ToString();
                if (MessageBox.Show("Time ran out!") == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    this.Close();
                }



            }
        }
    }

Comment: private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            counter--;
            if (counter == 0)
            


                timer1.Stop();
                label1.Text = counter.ToString();
                if (MessageBox.Show("Time ran out!") == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    this.Close();
                }



            }
        }
    }

Comment: when i wrote this i appeard a messagebox every second :(

Comment: That's because you're not using {} after the if. If you do that it assumes you only want the next line under the if. You should never do it.

Comment: thanks :D I actually started with programming few weeks ago :)

Comment: private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            counter--;
            if (counter.Equals(0))
            {


                timer1.Stop();
                label1.Text = counter.ToString();
                if (MessageBox.Show("Time ran out!") == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    this.Close();
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: now the button wont work why?